# retrieve customize_register setting from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve some customizer settings that I initiated.

```
function notop_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'header_images', array(
        'title' => 'Header Images',
        'priority' => 2,
        'description' => "Add images with links to be redirected to when the images are clicked",
    ) );

    // Add color scheme setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_image_1_setting', array(
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'option',
    ) );


    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Upload_Control($wp_customize,'header_image_1_control', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Import Image', 'notop' ),
        'section'  => 'header_images',
        'settings' => 'header_image_1_setting',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'notop_customize_register' );
```

How do I get the url of header_image_1?

I thought it might be get_theme_mod('header_image_1_setting'); but that hasn't worked so far. Also, I'm not sure if I'm actually supposed to call the customize_register file in my index somewhere or if it's okay the way it is.

Comment: You should be able to use `get_option('header_image_1_setting')`

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks Cale. I spent about 10 hours today trying to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

[cale_b's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31213596/#comment50430648_31213596) is the answer.

```
get_option('header_image_1_setting')
```

=> http://...